# Google Adwords/Ads AdGroupAdService

Tags: google-ads-api, adgroup

I was wondering, if I add and delete some ads with the service AdGroupAdService, using the method mutate, If It returns me some errors ( not in all the operations i want to upload ), does it perfom correctly the others operations?
My initial guess was it does, but after a few checks, it does not.
So Am I missing something?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

That is a feature known as partial failure. 
If you set it to true within your SOAP header, then the program will run the operations that have no errors correctly. 
If it is not set to true, then the whole program will fail if any operation has an error.